# Improve resolution of WMS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, resolution

Does anybody know how the resolution of wms/xyz-tiles like Google Earth can be improved? In comparison to the original services at the respective Google websites the resolution at higher zoom level is quite low...

Alternatively, what alternatives are there to the common used xyz-tiles like [https://mt1.google.com/vt/s=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](https://mt1.google.com/vt/s=s&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

Any hints?

Comment: For a WMS GetMap request you can Increase image size (height/width) and decrease size of BoundingBox for the area of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Mapbox satellite as an alternative to google XYZ tiles

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=<MAPBOX_TOKEN_HERE>
```

you will need to register on Mapbox to obtain an API Token. You can also replace satellite-v9 with appropriate base map layer of your choice.

You can also add them using WMTS, check this.  https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/mapbox-arcgis-qgis/